# Calling multiple playlist from Spotify API using React JS

Tags: reactjs, spotify

I am trying to display 12 playlist from Spotify using the spotifywebapi.getPlaylist() function which takes the playlist id. I can call all of them separately but when I componentDidMount them only the last one will render and show on the page.

I have tried putting the playlist id into an array of objects and calling it like this spotifyWebApi.getPlaylist(`${id}`)but I get an error of "no playlist id input"

does anyone know how to display/call multiple playlist at once to render on the page using spotify?

here is calling one playlist:

```
ariesPlaylist = () => {
      spotifyWebApi.getPlaylist('37i9dQZF1DX2DC3Q7JOmYe')
        .then((data) => {
          console.log('updating')
          console.log(data)
          this.setState({
            playlistData: {
              name: data.name,
              url: data.external_urls.spotify,
              image: data.images[0].url
            }
      })
    })
}
```

and this is the componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.ariesPlaylist();
      this.taurusPlaylist();
      this.geminiPlaylist();
      this.cancerPlaylist();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! kindly share code snippet of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I think Promise.all() may help you in this case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all